# Why do I get a syntax error for placing if/else in a coffeescript function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am placing conditional logic in a coffeescript function and I am getting a on helpful compiling error for rails `can't parse 'compile ((execjs):17:19)'`

Here is my simplified code:

```
defaultFilterByDate = () ->
  if (true) {
    alert 'hello'
  }
```

When I reload the page. My rails environment does not like this. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: because it's not valid coffeescript. I suggest you consult http://coffeescript.org/ and its interactive console and comparison snippets. (hint: parentheses and braces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because coffeescript is valid without `{}`, the correct code would be:

```
defaultFilterByDate = () ->
  if (true)
    alert 'hello'
```

Without `()` or even in 1 line is also okay:

```
defaultFilterByDate = () -> if true then alert 'hello'
```